# How to deal with r(123) in did_imputation command?

Tags: stata

I ran the `did_imputation command` in Stata and got  faced the `ms_get_version` error. I follow a [discussion from Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1625693-what-does-command-ms_get_version-is-unrecognized-mean-and-how-i-should-deal-with-that) to run the code below to fix:

```
ssc install ftools
```

However, after that, when running `did_imputation`, I faced the problem of `r(123)`. I had a look around and they say it may be due to name encoding, number of variables .... however, none of them are my problem. I only have 1 milion observations, while my Stata package allows me up to 1 billion observations.

I am wondering if there is any guidance for helping me to sort it out.

```
did_imputation lnq_r id2 ndate nbanned_date, horizons(0/10) pretrend(10)
```

I have tried to look at the variables and I am sure all of them are numeric or already encoded to numeric by using `encode`.

Update:

After learning the code from @NickCox, I got the resultsa below and I am still not sure what happened causing my error, from what I saw, it seems that the errors coming from time dimension but it is clear that these two time dimensions in the equationm were written under date DMY format so should not be non-integer

```
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- begin did_imputation ---
  - version 13.0
  - syntax varlist(min=4 max=4) [if] [in] [aw iw] [, wtr(varlist) sum Horizons(numlist >=0) ALLHorizons HBALance minn(integer 30) shift(integer 0) AUTOSample SAVEestimates(name
> ) SAVEWeights LOADWeights(varlist) AVGEFFectsby(varlist) fe(string) Controls(varlist) UNITControls(varlist) TIMEControls(varlist) CLUSter(varname) leaveout tol(real 0.000001)
>  maxit(integer 100) verbose nose PREtrends(integer 0) delta(integer 0) alpha(real 0.05)]
  - qui {
  - if ("`verbose'"!="") noi di "Starting"
  = if (""!="") noi di "Starting"
  - ms_get_version reghdfe, min_version("5.7.3")
    ms_get_version ftools, min_version("2.37.0")
    marksample touse, novarlist
    if ("`controls'"!="") markout `touse' `controls'
    if ("`unitcontrols'"!="") markout `touse' `unitcontrols'
    if ("`timecontrols'"!="") markout `touse' `timecontrols'
    if ("`cluster'"!="") markout `touse' `cluster', strok
    if ("`saveestimates'"!="") confirm new variable `saveestimates'
    if ("`saveweights'"!="") confirm new variable `saveweights'
    if ("`verbose'"!="") noi di "#00"
    tempvar wei
    if ("`weight'"=="") {
    gen `wei' = 1
    local weiexp ""
    }
    else {
    gen `wei' `exp'
    replace `wei' = . if `wei'==0
    markout `touse' `wei'
    if ("`sum'"=="") {
    sum `wei' if `touse'
    replace `wei' = `wei' * r(N)/r(sum)
    }
    local weiexp "[`weight'=`wei']"
    }
    local debugging = ("`verbose'"=="verbose")
    tokenize `varlist'
    local Y `1'
    local i `2'
    local t `3'
    local ei `4'
    markout `touse' `Y' `t'
    markout `touse' `i', strok
    tempvar D K
    if ("`fe'"=="") local fe `i' `t'
    if ("`fe'"==".") {
    tempvar constant
    gen `constant' = 1
    local fe `constant'
    }
    local fecount = 0
    foreach fecurrent of local fe {
    if (("`fecurrent'"!="`i'" | "`unitcontrols'"=="") & ("`fecurrent'"!="`t'" | "`timecontrols'"=="")) {
    local ++fecount
    local fecopy `fecopy' `fecurrent'
    local fe`fecount' = subinstr("`fecurrent'","#"," ",.)
    markout `touse' `fe`fecount'', strok
    }
    }
    local fe `fecopy'
    if (`delta'==0) {
    cap tsset, noquery
    if (_rc==0) {
    if (r(timevar)=="`t'") {
    local delta = r(tdelta)
    if (`delta'!=1) noi di "Note: setting delta = `delta'"
    }
    }
    else local delta = 1
    }
    if (`delta'<=0 | mi(`delta')) {
    di as error "A problem has occured with determining delta. Please specify it explicitly."
    error 198
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#1"
    gen `K' = (`t'-`ei'+`shift')/`delta' if `touse'
    cap assert mi(`K') | mod(`K',1)==0
    if (_rc!=0) {
    di as error "There are non-integer values of the number of periods since treatment. Please check the time dimension of your data."
    error 198
    }
    gen `D' = (`K'>=0 & !mi(`K')) if `touse'
    if ("`avgeffectsby'"=="") local avgeffectsby = "`ei' `t'"
    if ("`cluster'"=="") local cluster = "`i'"
    if ("`autosample'"!="" & "`sum'"!="") {
    di as error "Autosample cannot be combined with sum. Please specify the sample explicitly"
    error 184
    }
    if ("`autosample'"!="" & "`hbalance'"!="") {
    di as error "Autosample cannot be combined with hbalance. Please specify the sample explicitly"
    error 184
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#2 `fe'"
    local wtr_count : word count `wtr'
    if (`wtr_count'==0) {
    tempvar wtr
    gen `wtr' = 1 if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    local wtrnames tau
    local wtr_count = 1
    }
    else {
    if (`wtr_count'==1) local wtrnames tau
    else local wtrnames ""
    local wtr_new_list
    foreach v of local wtr {
    tempvar `v'_new
    gen ``v'_new' = `v' if `touse'
    local wtr_new_list `wtr_new_list' ``v'_new'
    if (`wtr_count'>1) local wtrnames `wtrnames' tau_`v'
    }
    local wtr `wtr_new_list'
    }
    if (("`horizons'"!="" | "`allhorizons'"!="") & `wtr_count'>1) {
    di as error "Options horizons and allhorizons cannot be combined with multiple wtr variables"
    error 184
    }
    if ("`allhorizons'"!="") {
    if ("`horizons'"!="") {
    di as error "Options horizons and allhorizons cannot be combined"
    error 184
    }
    if ("`hbalance'"!="") di as error "Warning: combining hbalance with allhorizons may lead to very restricted samples. Consider specifying a smaller subset of horizons."
    levelsof `K' if `touse' & `D'==1 & `wtr'!=0 & !mi(`wtr'), local(horizons)
    }
    if ("`horizons'"!="") {
    if ("`hbalance'"=="hbalance") {
    tempvar in_horizons num_horizons_by_i min_weight_by_i max_weight_by_i
    local n_horizons = 0
    gen `in_horizons'=0 if `touse'
    foreach h of numlist `horizons' {
    replace `in_horizons'=1 if (`K'==`h') & `touse'
    local ++n_horizons
    }
    egen `num_horizons_by_i' = sum(`in_horizons') if `in_horizons'==1, by(`i')
    replace `wtr' = 0 if `touse' & (`in_horizons'==0 | (`num_horizons_by_i'<`n_horizons'))
    egen `min_weight_by_i' = min(`wtr'*`wei') if `touse' & `in_horizons'==1 & (`num_horizons_by_i'==`n_horizons'), by(`i')
    egen `max_weight_by_i' = max(`wtr'*`wei') if `touse' & `in_horizons'==1 & (`num_horizons_by_i'==`n_horizons'), by(`i')
    cap assert `max_weight_by_i'<=1.000001*`min_weight_by_i' if `touse' & `in_horizons'==1 & (`num_horizons_by_i'==`n_horizons')
    if (_rc>0) {
    di as error "Weights must be identical across periods for units in the balanced sample"
    error 498
    }
    drop `in_horizons' `num_horizons_by_i' `min_weight_by_i' `max_weight_by_i'
    }
    foreach h of numlist `horizons' {
    tempvar wtr`h'
    gen `wtr`h'' = `wtr' * (`K'==`h')
    local horlist `horlist' `wtr`h''
    local hornameslist `hornameslist' tau`h'
    }
    local wtr `horlist'
    local wtrnames `hornameslist'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "List: `wtr'"
    if (`debugging') noi di "Namelist: `wtrnames'"
    if ("`sum'"=="") {
    foreach v of local wtr {
    cap assert `v'>=0 if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    if (_rc!=0) {
    di as error "Negative wtr weights are only allowed if the sum option is specified"
    error 9
    }
    sum `v' `weiexp' if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    replace `v' = `v'/r(sum)
    }
    }
    local tau_num : word count `wtr'
    local ctrl_num : word count `controls'
    if (`debugging') noi di `tau_num'
    if (`debugging') noi di `"`wtr' | `wtrnames' | `controls'"'
    tempname b Nt
    matrix `b' = J(1,`tau_num'+`pretrends'+`ctrl_num',.)
    matrix `Nt' = J(1,`tau_num',.)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4.0"
    if ("`unitcontrols'"!="") local fe_i `i'##c.(`unitcontrols')
    if ("`timecontrols'"!="") local fe_t `t'##c.(`timecontrols')
    count if (`D'==0) & (`touse')
    if (r(N)==0) {
    if (`shift'==0) noi di as error "There are no untreated observations, i.e. those with `t'<`ei' or mi(`ei')."
    else noi di as error "There are no untreated observations, i.e. those with `t'<`ei'-`shift' or mi(`ei')."
    noi di as error "Please double-check the period & event time variables."
    noi di
    error 459
    }
    tempvar imput_resid
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4: reghdfe `Y' `controls' if (`D'==0) & (`touse') `weiexp', a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe', savefe) nocon keepsing resid(`imput_resid') cluster(`cluster')"
    if (`debugging') noi reghdfe `Y' `controls' if (`D'==0) & (`touse') `weiexp', a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe', savefe) nocon keepsing resid(`imput_resid') cluster(`cluster')
    else reghdfe `Y' `controls' if (`D'==0) & (`touse') `weiexp', a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe', savefe) nocon keepsing resid(`imput_resid') cluster(`cluster')verbose(-1)
    local dof_adj = (e(N)-1)/(e(N)-e(df_m)-e(df_a)) * (e(N_clust)/(e(N_clust)-1))
    if (`debugging') noi di "#5"
    tempvar Y0
    gen `Y0' = 0 if `touse'
    local feset = 1
    if ("`unitcontrols'"!="") {
    recover __hdfe`feset'__*, from(`i')
    replace `Y0' = `Y0' + __hdfe`feset'__ if `touse'
    local j=1
    foreach v of local unitcontrols {
    replace `Y0' = `Y0'+__hdfe`feset'__Slope`j'*`v' if `touse'
    local ++j
    }
    local ++feset
    }
    if ("`timecontrols'"!="") {
    recover __hdfe`feset'__*, from(`t')
    replace `Y0' = `Y0' + __hdfe`feset'__ if `touse'
    local j=1
    foreach v of local timecontrols {
    replace `Y0' = `Y0'+__hdfe`feset'__Slope`j'*`v' if `touse'
    local ++j
    }
    local ++feset
    }
    forvalues feindex = 1/`fecount' {
    recover __hdfe`feset'__, from(`fe`feindex'')
    replace `Y0' = `Y0' + __hdfe`feset'__ if `touse'
    local ++feset
    }
    foreach v of local controls {
    replace `Y0' = `Y0'+_b[`v']*`v' if `touse'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#7"
    if ("`saveestimates'"=="") tempvar effect
    else {
    local effect `saveestimates'
    cap confirm var `effect', exact
    if (_rc==0) drop `effect'
    }
    gen `effect' = `Y' - `Y0' if (`D'==1) & (`touse')
    drop __hdfe*
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8"
    if (`ctrl_num'>0) {
    forvalues h = 1/`ctrl_num' {
    local ctrl_current : word `h' of `controls'
    matrix `b'[1,`tau_num'+`pretrends'+`h'] = _b[`ctrl_current']
    local ctrlb`h' = _b[`ctrl_current']
    local ctrlse`h' = _se[`ctrl_current']
    }
    local ctrl_df = e(df_r)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4B"
    local list_ctrl_weps
    if ("`se'"!="nose") {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4C3"
    local ctrlvars ""
    forvalues h = 1/`ctrl_num' {
    local ctrl_current : word `h' of `controls'
    if (`ctrlb`h''!=0 | `ctrlse`h''!=0) local ctrlvars `ctrlvars' `ctrl_current'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4C4 `ctrlvars'"
    tempvar ctrlweight ctrlweight_product
    forvalues h = 1/`ctrl_num' {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4D `h'"
    tempvar ctrleps_w`h'
    if (`ctrlb`h''==0 & `ctrlse`h''==0) gen `ctrleps_w`h'' = 0
    else {
    local ctrl_current : word `h' of `controls'
    local rhsvars = subinstr(" `ctrlvars' "," `ctrl_current' "," ",.)
    reghdfe `ctrl_current' `rhsvars' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==0, a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') cluster(`cluster') resid(`ctrlweight')
    replace `ctrlweight' = `ctrlweight' * `wei'
    gen `ctrlweight_product' = `ctrlweight' * `ctrl_current'
    sum `ctrlweight_product' if `touse' & `D'==0
    replace `ctrlweight' = `ctrlweight'/r(sum)
    egen `ctrleps_w`h'' = total(`ctrlweight' * `imput_resid') if `touse', by(`cluster')
    replace `ctrleps_w`h'' = `ctrleps_w`h'' * sqrt(`dof_adj')
    drop `ctrlweight' `ctrlweight_product'
    }
    local list_ctrl_weps `list_ctrl_weps' `ctrleps_w`h''
    }
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#4.75 `list_ctrl_weps'"
    }
    tempvar need_imputation
    gen byte `need_imputation' = 0
    foreach v of local wtr {
    replace `need_imputation'=1 if `touse' & `D'==1 & `v'!=0 & !mi(`v')
    }
    replace `touse' = (`touse') & (`D'==0 | `need_imputation')
    count if mi(`effect') & `need_imputation'
    if r(N)>0 {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8b `wtr'"
    cap drop cannot_impute
    gen byte cannot_impute = mi(`effect') & `need_imputation'
    count if cannot_impute==1
    if ("`autosample'"=="") {
    noi di as error "Could not impute FE for " r(N) " observations. Those are saved in the cannot_impute variable. Use the autosample option if you would like those observation
> s to be dropped from the sample automatically."
    error 198
    }
    else {
    assert "`sum'"==""
    local j = 1
    qui foreach v of local wtr {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8d sum `v' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==1"
    local outputname : word `j' of `wtrnames'
    sum `v' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==1
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8dd " r(sum)
    assert abs(r(sum)-1)<10^-5 | abs(r(sum))<10^-5
    count if `touse' & `D'==1 & cannot_impute==1 & `v'!=0 & !mi(`v')
    local n_cannot_impute = r(N)
    if (`n_cannot_impute'>0) {
    sum `v' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==1 & cannot_impute!=1 & `v'!=0 & !mi(`v')
    if (r(N)==0) {
    replace `v' = 0 if `touse' & `D'==1
    local autosample_drop `autosample_drop' `outputname'
    }
    else {
    replace `v' = `v'/r(sum) if `touse' & `D'==1 & cannot_impute!=1
    replace `v' = 0 if cannot_impute==1
    local autosample_trim `autosample_trim' `outputname'
    }
    }
    local ++j
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8e"
    replace `touse' = `touse' & cannot_impute!=1
    if ("`autosample_drop'"!="") noi di "Warning: suppressing the following coefficients because FE could not be imputed for any units: `autosample_drop'."
    if ("`autosample_trim'"!="") noi di "Warning: part of the sample was dropped for the following coefficients because FE could not be imputed: `autosample_trim'."
    }
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#8c"
    tempvar tnorm
    gen `tnorm' = rnormal() if (`touse') & (`D'==0 | `need_imputation')
    reghdfe `tnorm' `controls' if (`D'==0) & (`touse'), a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') nocon keepsing verbose(-1)
    local df_m_control = e(df_m)
    local df_a_control = e(df_a)
    reghdfe `tnorm' `controls' , a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') nocon keepsing verbose(-1)
    local df_m_full = e(df_m)
    local df_a_full = e(df_a)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9 `df_m_control' `df_m_full' `df_a_control' `df_a_full'"
    if (`df_m_control'<`df_m_full') {
    di as error "Could not run imputation for some observations because some controls are collinear in the D==0 subsample but not in the full sample"
    if ("`autosample'"!="") di as error "Please note that autosample does not know how to deal with this. Please correct the sample manually"
    error 481
    }
    if (`df_a_control'<`df_a_full') {
    di as error "Could not run imputation for some observations because some absorbed variables/FEs are collinear in the D==0 subsample but not in the full sample"
    if ("`autosample'"!="") di as error "Please note that autosample does not know how to deal with this. Please correct the sample manually"
    error 481
    }
    local droplist
    tempvar abswei
    gen `abswei' = .
    local j = 1
    foreach v of local wtr {
    local outputname : word `j' of `wtrnames'
    replace `abswei' = abs(`v') if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    sum `abswei' `weiexp'
    if (r(sum)!=0) {
    replace `abswei' = (`v'*`wei'/r(sum))^2 if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    sum `abswei'
    if (r(sum)>1/`minn') {
    local droplist `droplist' `outputname'
    replace `v' = 0 if `touse'
    }
    }
    else local droplist `droplist' `outputname'
    local ++j
    }
    if ("`droplist'"!="") noi di "WARNING: suppressing the following coefficients from estimation because of insufficient effective sample size: `droplist'. To report them neve
> rtheless, set the minn option to a smaller number or 0, but keep in mind that the estimates may be unreliable and their SE may be downward biased."
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9.5"
    if (`pretrends'>0) {
    tempname pretrendvar
    tempvar preresid
    forvalues h = 1/`pretrends' {
    gen `pretrendvar'`h' = (`K'==-`h') if `touse'
    local pretrendvars `pretrendvars' `pretrendvar'`h'
    local prenames `prenames' pre`h'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9A reghdfe `Y' `controls' `pretrendvars' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==0,  a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') cluster(`cluster') resid(`preresid')"
    reghdfe `Y' `controls' `pretrendvars' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==0, a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') cluster(`cluster') resid(`preresid')
    forvalues h = 1/`pretrends' {
    matrix `b'[1,`tau_num'+`h'] = _b[`pretrendvar'`h']
    local preb`h' = _b[`pretrendvar'`h']
    local prese`h' = _se[`pretrendvar'`h']
    }
    local pre_df = e(df_r)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9B"
    local list_pre_weps
    if ("`se'"!="nose") {
    matrix pre_b = e(b)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9C1"
    matrix pre_V = e(V)
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9C2"
    local dof_adj = (e(N)-1)/(e(N)-e(df_m)-e(df_a)) * (e(N_clust)/(e(N_clust)-1))
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9C3"
    local pretrendvars ""
    forvalues h = 1/`pretrends' {
    if (`preb`h''!=0 | `prese`h''!=0) local pretrendvars `pretrendvars' `pretrendvar'`h'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9C4 `pretrendvars'"
    tempvar preweight
    forvalues h = 1/`pretrends' {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9D `h'"
    tempvar preeps_w`h'
    if (`preb`h''==0 & `prese`h''==0) gen `preeps_w`h'' = 0
    else {
    local rhsvars = subinstr(" `pretrendvars' "," `pretrendvar'`h' "," ",.)
    reghdfe `pretrendvar'`h' `controls' `rhsvars' `weiexp' if `touse' & `D'==0, a(`fe_i' `fe_t' `fe') cluster(`cluster') resid(`preweight')
    replace `preweight' = `preweight' * `wei'
    sum `preweight' if `touse' & `D'==0 & `pretrendvar'`h'==1
    replace `preweight' = `preweight'/r(sum)
    egen `preeps_w`h'' = total(`preweight' * `preresid') if `touse', by(`cluster')
    replace `preeps_w`h'' = `preeps_w`h'' * sqrt(`dof_adj')
    drop `preweight'
    }
    local list_pre_weps `list_pre_weps' `preeps_w`h''
    }
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#9.75"
    }
    count if `D'==0 & `touse'
    local Nc = r(N)
    count if `touse'
    local Nall = r(N)
    tempvar effectsum
    gen `effectsum' = .
    local j = 1
    foreach v of local wtr {
    local outputname : word `j' of `wtrnames'
    if (`debugging') noi di "Reporting `j' `v' `outputname'"
    replace `effectsum' = `effect'*`v'*`wei' if (`D'==1) & (`touse')
    sum `effectsum'
    matrix `b'[1,`j'] = r(sum)
    count if `D'==1 & `touse' & `v'!=0 & !mi(`v')
    matrix `Nt'[1,`j'] = r(N)
    local ++j
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#10"
    if ("`se'"!="nose") {
    cap drop __w_*
    tempvar tag_clus resid
    egen `tag_clus' = tag(`cluster') if `touse'
    gen `resid' = `Y' - `Y0' if (`touse') & (`D'==0)
    if ("`loadweights'"=="") {
    local weightvars = ""
    foreach vn of local wtrnames {
    local weightvars `weightvars' __w_`vn'
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#11a imputation_weights `i' `t' `D' , touse(`touse') wtr(`wtr') saveweights(`weightvars') wei(`wei') fe(`fe') controls(`controls') unitcontrols(`un
> itcontrols') timecontrols(`timecontrols') tol(`tol') maxit(`maxit')"
    noi imputation_weights `i' `t' `D', touse(`touse') wtr(`wtr') saveweights(`weightvars') wei(`wei') fe(`fe') controls(`controls') unitcontrols(`unitcontrols') timecontrols(`
> timecontrols') tol(`tol') maxit(`maxit') `verbose'
    local Niter = r(iter)
    }
    else {
    local weightvars `loadweights'
    }
    local list_weps = ""
    local j = 1
    foreach v of local wtr {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#11b `v'"
    local weightvar : word `j' of `weightvars'
    tempvar clusterweight smartweight smartdenom avgtau eps_w`j'
    egen `clusterweight' = total(`wei'*`v') if `touse' & (`D'==1), by(`cluster' `avgeffectsby')
    egen `smartdenom' = total(`clusterweight' * `wei' * `v') if `touse' & (`D'==1), by(`avgeffectsby')
    gen `smartweight' = `clusterweight' * `wei' * `v' / `smartdenom' if `touse' & (`D'==1)
    replace `smartweight' = 0 if mi(`smartweight') & `touse' & (`D'==1)
    egen `avgtau' = sum(`effect'*`smartweight') if (`touse') & (`D'==1), by(`avgeffectsby')
    replace `resid' = `effect'-`avgtau' if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    if ("`leaveout'"!="") {
    if (`debugging') noi di "#11LO"
    count if `smartdenom'>0 & ((`clusterweight'^2)/`smartdenom'>0.99999) & (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    if (r(N)>0) {
    local outputname : word `j' of `wtrnames'
    di as error `"Cannot compute leave-out standard errors because of "' r(N) `" observations for coefficient "`outputname'""'
    di as error "This most likely happened because there are cohorts with only one unit or cluster (and the default value for avgeffectsby  is used)."
    di as error "Consider using the avgeffectsby option with broader observation groups. Do not address this problem by using non-leave-out standard errors, as they may be down
> ward biased for the same reason."
    error 498
    }
    replace `resid' = `resid' * `smartdenom' / (`smartdenom'-(`clusterweight'^2)) if (`touse') & (`D'==1)
    }
    egen `eps_w`j'' = sum(`wei'*`weightvar'*`resid') if `touse', by(`cluster')
    local list_weps `list_weps' `eps_w`j''
    drop `clusterweight' `smartweight' `smartdenom' `avgtau'
    local ++j
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "11c"
    tempname V
    if (`debugging') noi di "11d `list_weps' | `list_pre_weps' | `list_ctrl_weps'"
    matrix accum `V' = `list_weps' `list_pre_weps' `list_ctrl_weps' if `tag_clus', nocon
    if (`debugging') noi di "11e `wtrnames' | `prenames' | `controls'"
    matrix rownames `V' = `wtrnames' `prenames' `controls'
    matrix colnames `V' = `wtrnames' `prenames' `controls'
    if ("`saveweights'"=="" & "`loadweights'"=="") drop __w_*
    }
    if (`debugging') noi di "#12"
    matrix colnames `b' = `wtrnames' `prenames' `controls'
    matrix colnames `Nt' = `wtrnames'
    ereturn post `b' `V', esample(`touse') depname(`Y') obs(`Nall')
    ereturn matrix Nt = `Nt'
    ereturn scalar Nc = `Nc'
    ereturn local depvar `Y'
    ereturn local cmd did_imputation
    ereturn local droplist `droplist'
    ereturn local autosample_drop `autosample_drop'
    ereturn local autosample_trim `autosample_trim'
    if ("`Niter'"!="") ereturn scalar Niter = `Niter'
    if (`pretrends'>0 & "`se'"!="nose") {
    test `prenames', df(`pre_df')
    ereturn scalar pre_F = r(F)
    ereturn scalar pre_p = r(p)
    ereturn scalar pre_df = `pre_df'
    }
    }
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- end did_imputation ---
r(123);
```

Comment: See https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1698159-why-using-the-same-code-but-can-run-in-one-machine-and-cannot-run-in-another-machine-resulting-r-123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.   error 123
invalid numlist has too many elements
r(123);
```

hints that you may be asking too much. Not much else can be said helpfully without access to your data. But

```
set trace on 
set tracedepth 1
```

before running your command may indicate where the error occurs. If necessary, bump up `tracedepth` to 2, 3, and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Nick Cox, I have tried for tracedepth. However, from what I saw, it seems that the errors coming from time dimension but it is clear that these two time dimensions in the equationm were written under date DMY format so should not be non-integer. Could you please help me further? Thank you

Comment: Sorry,  but beyond suggesting that you try the `verbose` option I can't help further.

Answer (score 2):

The help file for `did_imputation` indicates this package has two dependencies: `ftools` and `reghdfe`. Have you confirmed you've installed both?

```
ssc install ftools
ssc install reghdfe
```